# ksh set-o pipefail is not inherited by scripts

Tags: ksh

I would like to have set -o pipefail set "always" (.kshrc) but consider the following trivial example:

```
#!/bin/ksh
  function fun {
      return 99
  }
if [[ $1 == 'pipe' ]] ; then
   set -o pipefail
fi
if fun | tee /tmp/bork.txt ; then 
    print "fun returned 0"
else
    print "fun nonzero"
fi

This results in:
/home/khb>./b pipe    
fun nonzero                          GOOD what we want
/home/khb>./b                        
fun returned 0                       What we expect without pipefail!
/home/khb>set -o pipefail
/home/khb>./b
fun returned 0                 BAD: expected the set to impact inferior shells
```

No doubt this should be obvious, but other than creating an environment variable and having every script reference it ... or sourcing a common set of definitions ... what other options are there to arrange for this option to be "found" in each script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I once did something like `(fun; echo $? > result.x) | tee /tmp/bork.txt`, but I have no longer access to the code I wrote. Can you make a function checked_run() that writes the result to a variable $keithResult and test that after the pipe?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly awkward solution would be to have `set -o pipefail` in your `~/.profile` file and then write scripts that always invoke *ksh* as a login shell, i.e. by using `#!/bin/ksh -l` as the hash-bang line.

A less (?) awkward solution would be to put `set -o pipe fail` in the file pointed to by `$ENV` and then invoke *ksh* with `-E` (instead of `-l` above). However, shells parsing `$ENV` are usually interactive shells...

Comment: It isn't effective in the kshrc ( echo $ENV
/Users/khb/.kshrc) ./b 
fun returned 0, nor does the -E impact the result

Comment: Strange, both approaches works for me. Did you change the `#!`-line? Use `#!/bin/ksh -l` if you put `set -o pipefail` in `~/.profile`, but `#!/bin/ksh -E` if you put it in `$ENV`.

Comment: I'm using ksh93, `Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01` (default shell on Mac OS X 10.10.3) by the way. What kornshell are you using?

Comment: I must have mixed the -E and -l cases up, because it is working now on Mac and a couple of Linux variants I have handy.  Thank you.